# How can I list all files in a directory using Perl?

Tags: perl, directory

I usually use something like

```
my $dir="/path/to/dir";
opendir(DIR, $dir) or die "can't open $dir: $!";
my @files = readdir DIR;
closedir DIR;
```

or sometimes I use `glob`, but anyway, I always need to add a line or two to filter out `.` and `..` which is quite annoying.
How do you usually go about this common task?

Comment: From the explosion of responses, you can see that It Entirely Depends on What Results You Want to Get. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[How do I read in the contents of a directory in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566/how-do-i-read-in-the-contents-of-a-directory-in-perl)*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will normally use the `glob` method:

```
for my $file (glob "$dir/*") {
    #do stuff with $file
}
```

This works fine unless the directory has lots of files in it.  In those cases you have to switch back to `readdir` in a `while` loop (putting `readdir` in list context is just as bad as the `glob`):

```
open my $dh, $dir
    or die "could not open $dir: $!";

while (my $file = readdir $dh) {
    next if $file =~ /^[.]/;
    #do stuff with $file
}
```

Often though, if I am reading a bunch of files in a directory, I want to read them in a recursive manner.  In those cases I use `File::Find`:

```
use File::Find;

find sub {
    return if /^[.]/;
    #do stuff with $_ or $File::Find::name
}, $dir;
```

Comment: The use of `[.]` is very curious---why do you prefer that to `\.`?

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young I just like it better.  It seems less noisy (see [leaning toothpick syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome)).  Also, and this is rationalizing, escapes in regex tend to mean "the next character does something special" (e.g. `\x{2e}`), but `\.` means it is just a period.  Since most characters don't have special meaning inside a character classes, it makes a nice escape mechanism.

Answer (score 14):

```
my @files = grep {!/^\./} readdir DIR;
```

This will exclude all the dotfiles as well, but that's usually What You Want.

Answer (score 9):

I often use [File::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Slurp). Benefits include: (1) Dies automatically if the directory does not exist. (2) Excludes `.` and `..` by default. It's behavior is like `readdir` in that it does not return the full paths.

```
use File::Slurp qw(read_dir);

my $dir = '/path/to/dir';
my @contents = read_dir($dir);
```

Another useful module is [File::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Util), which provides many options when reading a directory. For example:

```
use File::Util;
my $dir = '/path/to/dir';
my $fu = File::Util->new;
my @contents = $fu->list_dir( $dir, '--with-paths', '--no-fsdots' );
```

Comment: ...which wasn't a requirement from the OP. He only wanted to filter out `.` and `..`.

Comment: Nice. Can I make it return the full paths (not the basenames)?

Comment: @David B You might also consider `File::Util`, as shown in the edited answer.

Answer (score 7):

If some of the dotfiles are important,

```
my @files = grep !/^\.\.?$/, readdir DIR;
```

will only exclude `.` and `..`

Comment: Well, it might exclude "..\n", which is legal in Unix. Not that I wish that filename on anyone, but people do strange things to see if someone will ignore a file they've snuck into your directory. You can fix that with a \z instead of $ :)

Answer (score 5):

When I just want the files (as opposed to directories), I use `grep` with a `-f` test:

```
my @files = grep { -f } readdir $dir;
```

Comment: This will only work if the directory handle is for the current directory.

Comment: @Chris: good point, one would need to chdir first, or construct an absolute path name in the grep with `File::Spec->catfile($dirname, $_)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Chris and Ether for your recommendations. I used the following to read a listing of all files (excluded directories), from a directory handle referencing a directory other than my current directory, into an array. The array was always missing one file when not using the absolute path in the grep statement

```
use File::Slurp; 

print "\nWhich folder do you want to replace text? " ;
chomp (my $input = <>);
if ($input eq "") {
print "\nNo folder entered exiting program!!!\n";
exit 0;
} 

opendir(my $dh, $input) or die "\nUnable to access directory $input!!!\n"; 

my @dir = grep { -f "$input\\$_" } readdir $dh;
```