# Can NOT List directory including space using Perl in Windows Platform

Tags: perl, glob

In order to list pathes in Windows,I wrote below Perl function(executed under StrawBerry runtime environment).

```
sub listpath
{
   my $path = shift;
   my @list = glob "$path/*";
   #my @list = <$path/*>;
   my @pathes = grep {  -d and $_ ne "." and $_ ne ".." } @list;
}
```

But it can't parse directory including space correctly, for example:

When I issued following code:
  listpath("e:/test/test1/test11/test111/test1111/test11111 - Copy");

The function returned an array including two elements:

1: e:/test/test1/test11/test111/test1111/test11111
2: -

I am wondering if glob could parse above space directories. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try [`bsd_glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Glob.html) instead:

```
use File::Glob ':glob';
my @list = bsd_glob "$path/*";
```

Comment: Only for record: from the up-to-date doc on [`File::Glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Glob.html#EXPORTS), it's discouraged to use the export flag `:glob`, prefer `:bsd_glob`.

Answer (score 2):

Even if the topic has been answered long time ago, I recently encounter the same problem, and a quick search gives me another solution, from [perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=189183) (last reply):

```
my $path = shift;
$path =~ s/ /\\ /g;
my @list = glob "$path/*";
```

But prefer `bsd_glob`, it supports also a couple of other neat features, such as `[]` for character class.

Answer (score 1):

The question is about Windows platform, where Bentoy13's solution does not work because the backslash would be mistaken for a path separator.

Here's an option if for whatever reason you don't want to go with bsd_glob: wrap the offensive part of the path in double quotes. This can be one directory name (`path\\"to my"\\file.txt`) or several directory names (`"path\\to my"\\file.txt`). Slash instead of backslash usually works, too. Of course, they don't *have* to include a space, so this here always works:

```
my @list = glob "\"$path\"/*";
```

remember, it's a Windows solution. Whether it works under Linux depends on context.