# How do I record the name of the files in a folder?

Tags: windows, perl

for example i have :
file directory: C:\Users\Desktop\program
files in directory: cheese(folder) ,veggie(txt file), meat(doc file)
How do i record down the names of the files and folder in the directory?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You forgot to include your code so far and details of exactly where you are having problems.

Comment: See the following: [How do I read in the contents of a directory in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566/how-do-i-read-in-the-contents-of-a-directory-in-perl)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html):

```
my @files = <*>;
```

This will give you all of the files in the current directory.

This method is convenient if you only want to find certain files:

```
my @jpegs = <*.jpg>;
```

If that isn't the directory you want, [change to the current directory](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chdir.html) or include the path:

```
my @files = </foo/bar*>;
```

Note that you should [use forward slashes](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Glob.html#NOTES) even if doing this on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
opendir FOLDER, $folder or die "Cant open folder $folder: $!";
my @file= readdir FOLDER;
closedir FOLDER;
```

Comment: thanks!!
another question, how to i print the result in txt file?

Comment: @user2297543 another question - another question ;) and no, don't do that, only look at [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)