# Perl multiple files read replacing string, write to multiple files

Tags: perl

I have this code working, but this is only for one file with specific name, how can I let it does all .vb file in current folder and output with file name plus _1 in the back

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fhIn,  '<', 'file.vb'          or die $!;
open my $fhOut, '>', 'file_1.vb'        or die $!;

while (<$fhIn>) {
    print $fhOut "'01/20/2016 Added \ngpFrmPosition = Me.Location\n" if /MessageBox/ and !/'/;
    
    print $fhOut $_;
}

close $fhOut;
close $fhIn;
```

Comment: `enter code here` -- nice touch. How about [readdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html)? (It doesn't look like you've put much effort into researching and/or solving this problem on your own.)

Comment: It's not clear which part you're struggling with, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566/how-do-i-read-in-the-contents-of-a-directory-in-perl/22573) will get you 97% of the way there.

Comment: @MattJacob: `enter code here` is what the Stack Overflow page writes if you try to mark some if your post as code without selecting anything

Comment: @Borodin Ah, that makes sense. I obviously thought the OP was simply letting us know where we could deposit his fully working code for him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might approach it like this. (This assumes the script is running in the same directory as the .vb files).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# script running in same directory as the .vb files

for my $file (glob "*.vb") {

    my $outfile = $file =~ s/(?=\.vb$)/_1/r;
    print "$file $outfile\n"; # DEBUG 

    # open input and output files

    # do the while loop
}
```

The print statement in the loop is for debug purposes - to see if you are creating the new file names correctly. You can delete it or comment it out when you are satisfied you have got the files you want.

Update: Put the glob in the for loop instead of reading it to an array.